# One way sync using OneDrive

Tags: sync, onedrive, one-way-sync

I would like use OneDrive to back up my important files, however I once used a cloud storage and lost some files due to a technical error.

Is there a way to prevent OneDrive from writing and use it only for one directional sync - from my PC to the cloud?

Perhaps some sort of a mount point that would allow only read access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use a *real* backup solution, like [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/). It supports backing up to OneDrive. To accomplish this, it needs `python-requests` and `python-requests-oauthlib`.

Just call duplicity like this:

```
duplicity "/my/folder" "onedrive://path/to/backup"
```

You will then be prompted (in your browser) to grant duplicity access to all your stuff.

To use duplicity on Windows, you need Cygwin or a similar compatibility layer. It’ll probably work on WSL, too.

Answer (score 2):

OneDrive desktop app is a client to synchronize files between Office 365 and your computer. There is no setting to configure one way sync.

If you don't want some end-users make changes to some documents, you can set file permission or folder permission (Edit or Read) in OneDrive or SharePoint to control it.

Answer (score 1):

In OneDrive, you can restore previous versions of individual files; deleted files are kept in the Recycle bin for 30 days (if there is enough capacity). More details [on OneDrive support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/restore-your-onedrive-fa231298-759d-41cf-bcd0-25ac53eb8a15).

Also there are many online backup services, which can give you more safety for a few $ per month.